# Ruby regex parse string for two sets of numbers?

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex

I have been using [Rubular.com](http://rubular.com/) to come up with a regex pattern to try to parse this string for the values 596 and 777 and put them in an array:

```
Current mouse position: 596,777
```

I have been building this in IRB and testing it with `t.scan(/(?:\d)/)`

This yields: `["4", "5", "1", "1", "1", "3", "7"]` which is not correct.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to put a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
t.scan(/\d+/)
```

The quantifier `+` means *one or more*

Note: The [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:...)` is useless.

Answer (score -1):

```
str = "Current mouse position: 596,777"

x, y = str.split()[-1].split(",")
puts x, y


--output:--
596
777
```

...

```
str = "Current mouse position: 596,777"

x = str[-7..-5]
y = str[-3..-1]
puts x, y

--output:--
596
777
```